# L1-norm minimisation in MATLAB with Gurobi

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to solve the following optimisation problem in MATLAB:

```
Min sum(abs(x))
s.t. A*x = 0,
     lb <= x <= ub
```

where x is a dense vector, A is a sparse matrix, lb and ub are Real lower and upper bounds respectively.
It would be convenient to do so with the function linprog() or the LP solver Gurobi.
Do you know how to formulate this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective `minimize sum(abs(x))` can be translated to:

- `minimize sum(u)`
- s.t. `-u_i <= x_i <= u_i`
- (where `dim(x) == dim(u)`)

Comment: Dully noted. However, I'm having a hard time translating this into code. I'll get back to you when I get it.

Comment: Finally I solved it with your input, using the cvx toolbox for MATLAB and the LP solver gurobi
`cvx_begin
    cvx_solver gurobi
    variable s(n);
    variable x(n)
    minimize sum(s);
    subject to 
        A*x == 0;
        lb <= x <= ub;
        -s <= x <= s;
cvx_end`

Comment: @GeorgeC If you use cvx, then you don't need my reformulation as l1 / sum_abs is already available within this lib! [See here](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/funcref.html) (the norm-function is very general). But if my answer helped, think about accepting or upvoting it.

Comment: I noticed that cvx has a norm function, e.g. norm(x,1). Nevertheless, I realised that it was not truly satisfying my constraints, e.g., A.x only approximated 0 with a very high error. 
This was solved, e.g., A.x = 10^-10, when I used the formulation stated above.
Accepted and up-voted (if it doesn't show is because I just registered).
Thanks for the help!